# Image map not working in Firefox

Tags: image, firefox, dictionary

I'm trying to get an image map to work, currently its working in Chrome/IE but not Firefox.

The image map works in all three browsers when it is not used on a WordPress Page

```
        <img id="Image-Maps_4201308071445592" src="/images/layout/GatewayHeader.png" usemap="#Image-Maps_4201308071445592" border="0" width="370" height="95" alt="" />
        <map id="_Image-Maps_4201308071445592" name="Image-Maps_4201308071445592">
            <area shape="rect" coords="10,0,80,90" href="http://www.missouri.edu/" alt="University of Missouri" title="University of Missouri"    />
            <area shape="rect" coords="80,0,365,90" href="http://www.library.missouri.edu" alt="MU Libraries" title="MU Libraries"    />
        </map>
```

Heres the links to the two webpages

Works in Chrome/IE: http://library.missouri.edu/libraries/ellis/

Works in all three: http://library.missouri.edu/

Answer (score 1):

Check if your **map name** appears in the **MAP and IMG tag**

```
<map name="exampleMap">...

<img src="yourURL" usemap="#exampleMap">
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to w3c, the id attribute on a map element must have an the same value as the name attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the issue